# Combine multiple rows to single row group by Specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks similar to this here:

[image]

I would like to able to combine all that data when they have the same Id.

Which would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then section end) as section1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value1 end) as section1_value1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value2 end) as section1_value2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then section end) as section2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value1 end) as section2_value1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value2 end) as section2_value2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by section) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```